# VS2012: Page inspector and view in browser won't work

Tags: html, asp.net, visual-studio-2012

I am new to website development, and I am having trouble viewing my webpage in a browser.

When I try to open the webpage in page inspector/ choose "view in browser" I get the following error.

Page Inspector:

"The attached page is not running in a compatible Internet Explorer standards mode. To use the latest document mode add the following meta tag to the html page:  To try to dynamically add the meta tag for this session click here."

View in Browser:

"Uh-oh, something went wrong! Error Code: 500"

I've tried adding the meta tag to the source HTML and it still doesn't work. Also, I am following step-by-step tutorials on youtube, doing everything exactly the same, yet it still won't work. If I open a ASP.Net webforms site I can view it in the browser, I'm just having trouble viewing them when I start from an empty website form.

Here is the header of my html code.

```
**<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Registration.aspx.cs" Inherits="Registration" %> <!DOCTYPE html> <html xmlns="w3.org/1999/xhtml">; <head runat="server"><title></title> <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge"/>**
```

any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think there are something wrong in the IIS.

First, please check which IIS that the project used and check whether the ASP.NET Application Development Feature has installed. (Right click the project=>Properties=>Web)

If it used the default IIS Express please try to re-install the VS and try again. You could try to host it to local IIS and check the result.

Or 
(Right click the project=>Property Window => Managed Pipleline Mode > Classic